# Filter an SQL Array text[] for matching value containing a parameter

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table with a TEXT[] column. I want to return all rows that have at least one of the array value that contains my parameter.

Right now I'm doing `WHERE array_to_string(arr, ',') ilike '%myString%'`

But I feel their must be a better optimized way of doing that kind of search.
Plus I would also like to search for values begining or ending by my parameter.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table
(
    id                  BIGSERIAL,
    col_array           TEXT[],

    CONSTRAINT my_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

```sql
insert into my_table(col_array)
VALUES ('{ABC,DEF}'),
       ('{FGH,IJK}'),
       ('{LMN}'),
       ('{OPQ}');
       
select * from my_table where ARRAY_TO_STRING(col_array, ',') ilike '%F%';
```

this works as it returns only first 2 rows.

You can find a sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/09632/7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a sub-query:

```
select t.*
from my_table t
where exists (select *
              from unnest(t.col_array) as x(e)
              where x.e ilike '%F%')
```

---

You might want to re-consider your decision to de-normalize your model.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/arrays.html#ARRAYS-SEARCHING)

> Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of elements.

Comment: Thank's for your help @a_horse_with_no_name, I ended up doing that with `select 1` instead of `select *` and it works perfectly. 
I understand that Arrays are not meant to do this kind of filtering in SQL and I'll take that in consideration in the future

Comment: There is absolutely no difference in performance whatsoever between `select *` and `select 1` if you expect that.

Comment: I expected it would be more performant indeed. Would you have a link that explain why ?

Comment: The obvious proof is, that the expression is not even evaluated. you can write `(select 1/0 from ..)` and it won't throw an error, as it does when not used as a sub-query for `exists`

Comment: [Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-subquery.html#FUNCTIONS-SUBQUERY-EXISTS)  "*Since the result depends only on whether any rows are returned, and **not on the contents of those rows**, the output list of the subquery is normally unimportant*"

Comment: Indeed: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/09632/14 thank's for your help man !